# Factories for Models with Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

When there are associated models , it is known that specifying the association in both the models will create a cyclic dependency and causes a "stack level too deep" error . So what's the correct place to specify the relationship ? Please see these simple associations :

```
class Patient
  has_many :doctors, :through => :join_model
end

class Doctor
  has_many :patients, :through => :join_model
end
```

also

```
class User
  has_many :posts
end

class Post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

In the factories for these models , Which one is the right place to hold the associations ?

Comment: what do both examples have in common? i don't get it...

Comment: @phoet : Both examples have associations . One with "has many through" , the other with "has_many" . My question is , if you're creating factories for each of the examples , which of the factories will be the right place to specify relationships ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a section in the factory_girl readme that has an example for a `has_many` association: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations

i think there is no golden rule here. i usually have a default factory per model, that has a simple or no relations set and then i have special factories like `:user_with_posts` that are used for a variety of related tests.
i also often just build them up myself in the test themselfes `create(:user, posts: [create(:some_special_post)])`

Comment: That's the doc I was looking for ! Thank you @phoet .